# execution of loop stops after a function (with a success handler) is called

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am calling a function (Function2) in a loop that is running in a success handler of a function (Function1). In the first iteration of the loop when i call the function (Function2), the function is called and opertation is performedas specified in the success handler of called function (Function2). but after that the control doesnt shift to the loop in the success handler of first function (Function1) and loop is not executed anymore. The code below explains the scenario:

```
function Function1()
{
    clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    website = clientContext.get_web();
    var oList = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Test');
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(this.collListItem, 'Include(ID, LinkFilename, Sender, Created,  DocIcon)');
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, successHandler),
    Function.createDelegate(this, errorHandler)
    );

    function successHandler() {
        var itemsCount = this.collListItem.get_count();
        for (i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++) {
            var item = this.collListItem.itemAt(i);
            alert(item.get_fieldValues()["Created"]);
            Function2();
        }
    alert('Loop ends');
    }
    function errorHandler() {
    }
}
```

now Function 2 is as follows:

```
function Function2(){
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    var oList = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Test2');
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
    context.load(this.collListItem, 'Include(ID, BaseName, Created, ServerUrl)');
    context.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, success),
    Function.createDelegate(this, error)
    );
    function success() {
        var itemsCount = this.collListItem.get_count();
        for (i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++) {
            var item = this.collListItem.itemAt(i);
            alert(item.get_fieldValues()["ServerUrl"]);
        }
    }
    function error(){
    }
 }
```

Now the problem I am facing is that, the code runs just for the first iteration of the loop in first function even if `itemsCount` is greater than 1 (after that the code that is written below the loop (the alert displaying "loop ends") even doesn't execute).
I am unable to spot whats going wrong, your suggestions are greatly welcomed. Please guide me through this.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tips:

1. Use Chrome and the Developer Console (F12) -> Network Tab to view the Response from the requests.
2. Add some console.log statements to see if your function is being called but not always reaching the success callback. For example:

> ```
> function Function2() {
>   console.log("Function2");
>   var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
>   var web = context.get_web();
>   var oList = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Test2');
>   var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
>   this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
>   context.load(this.collListItem, 'Include(ID, BaseName, Created, ServerUrl)');
>   context.executeQueryAsync(
>       Function.createDelegate(this, success),
>       Function.createDelegate(this, error)
>   );
>
>   function success() {
>       var itemsCount = this.collListItem.get_count();
>       for (i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++) {
>           var item = this.collListItem.itemAt(i);
>           alert(item.get_fieldValues()["ServerUrl"]);
>       }
>   }
>
>   function error(sender, args) {
>       console.log("Request failed: " + args.get_message() + ". " + args.get_stackTrace());
>   }
> }
> ```

Make sure that you have the Developer Tools open when you are using console.log as these statements will cause errors in IE with the Developer Tools closed.